# Refractive index calculation without using snell's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light

If I have a ray of light travelling from a transparent medium to the air in 70 degrees in the medium and 52 degrees in the air, how can I calculate the refractive index of the transparent medium without using a calculator? (not using snell's law)

Comment: may i ask why exactly you do not want to use snell's law

Comment: Because I am unable to calculate without computer, or taylor series the sine of 70 and 52 degrees.

Comment: OK I can help you.  Use formulae for sin  (a+b) for 70 make 60+10 for 52 use 60 -8 now use $sin\theta=\theta$ (for small theta) and $\cos \theta=1$. You will get approximate answer. Mind that the angle is in radian in $\sin\theta=\theta$ expression.

Comment: the answer from my method comes to be 1.19299 whereas exact number is 1.19248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Use Snell's law:
$$
n_1\sin\theta_1 = n_2\sin\theta_2
$$

I don't think you don't want to use Snell Law. You probably are asking how to evaluate sine with only paper and pencil (no calculator). Then, you can expand $\sin\theta$ around zero:
$$
\sin x\approx x - \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \frac{1}{5!}x^5 - \frac{1}{7!}x^7 + O(x^9)
$$

Good luck with the amount of paper you will use. In addition, the area of mathematics that shows how to calculate anything using only paper and pencil is called [Numerical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis). You might want to take a look. In addition, if your angle is small (close to zero), then $\sin\theta\approx\theta$, then Snell's law can be approximated and computed with paper and pencil:

$$
n_1\theta_1 = n_2\theta_2
$$